# What is the difference between Red Hat AMQ and Apache ActiveMQ?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis, amq

I am providing a design for a new project and I am trying to understand which JMS provider to use. Is there any difference between Red Hat AMQ and Apache ActiveMQ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latest version of Red Hat AMQ (i.e. the 7.x releases) is more than just a message broker. It is a *platform* consisting of a message broker (based on Apache ActiveMQ Artemis), a message router (based on [Apache Qpid Dispatch Router](https://qpid.apache.org/components/dispatch-router/index.html)), and a suite of clients with different language bindings and protocol support.

Red Hat AMQ broker is based on the upstream ActiveMQ project, but depending on which version of Red Hat AMQ you're using you'll get a different ActiveMQ broker. Red Hat AMQ 6.x broker is based on ActiveMQ 5.x whereas Red Hat AMQ 7.x broker is based on ActiveMQ Artemis 2.x.  Aside from that, the Red Hat AMQ brokers are usually (but not always) based on an a public release of the corresponding ActiveMQ project broker with potentially a number of additional code changes to address customer-specific issues, branding changes for the web console, etc.  Red Hat also does additional testing, has independent documentation, and commercial support as well.

Comment: thanks Justin. Does AMQ in Red Hat AMQ stand for Active MQ or something else?

Comment: The "AMQ" is just the product name.  It doesn't stand for anything else.

Comment: is there any difference between active mq and a queue?

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  Apache ActiveMQ is a message broker.  A queue is a component within a broker that you can put messages on and consume messages from.

Comment: @JustinBertram Can I use RedHat AMQ in my project without license/support? i searched and couldn't find any info.

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan, you should ask this as a new question rather than as a comment here.